# I changed my CSS color of background for the body to black but its white still for some reason

Tags: html, css, colors

Hi so I tried to change the background on the body of my HTML document but there seems to be a white line when everything else is the background is black which is what I want. By the way I want to mention that I do have bootstrap implemented in the head section of my html doc, I'm using bootstrap 4.4.1, so I believe that could be the other problem as to why my background isn't what I want it to be, but couldn't figure it out after fiddling and looking around for answers for some time.

Although I changed in my CSS for the background color to be black. [image]Simply I made it `body {background: black;}` in my CSS, Theres still a white spot there and when I go to inspect the element it says that the body's color is still #FFFFFF which is white. So yeah in my CSS I tried to change it by targeting the body and it still did not work.

Comment: Either you are cached or you are doing something wrong and we have no clue since we would just be guessing since no code is provided.

Comment: You've already got the inspector open. Have a look at how the rules are applied. Your CSS for your custom body background colour is probably higher up in the cascade than the bootstrap stylesheet. If you have a look a the bootstrap stylesheet the body background colour does not have high specificity or an !important tag